# SQL left join but only take the specific condition on a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables, the first is a table that contains status and the second is contains balance. I want to join those two tables but with only specific status on the first table

Sample Data Table 1

```
+------------------+------------------+--------------+
|   appsflyer_id   |   customer_id    |    status    |
+------------------+------------------+--------------+
|       AA1        |        123       |     NEW      |
|       AA1        |        123       |    ACTIVE    |
|       AA1        |        124       |     NEW      |
|       AA1        |        124       |    ACTIVE    |
+------------------+------------------+--------------+
```

Sample Data Table 2

```
+------------------+--------------+
|   customer_id    |   balance    |
+------------------+--------------+
|        123       |     100      |
|        124       |     250      |
+------------------+--------------+
```

Desired output

```
+------------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+
|   appsflyer_id   |   customer_id    |    status    |     balance      |
+------------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+
|       AA1        |        123       |     NEW      | (null/zero/empty)|
|       AA1        |        123       |    ACTIVE    |     100          |
|       AA1        |        124       |     NEW      | (null/zero/empty)|
|       AA1        |        124       |    ACTIVE    |     250          |
+------------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

I tried to use:

```sql
SELECT appsflyer_id, a.customer_id, status, balance
FROM `table_1` a left join `table_2` b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

It will return multiple balance which is not quite right

```
+------------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+
|   appsflyer_id   |   customer_id    |    status    |     balance      |
+------------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+
|       AA1        |        123       |     NEW      |     100          |
|       AA1        |        123       |    ACTIVE    |     100          |
|       AA1        |        124       |     NEW      |     250          |
|       AA1        |        124       |    ACTIVE    |     250          |
+------------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want CASE

```
SELECT a.appsflyer_id, a.customer_id, a.status, 
      CASE WHEN a.status = 'ACTIVE' THEN b.balance END balance
FROM `table_1` a 
LEFT JOIN `table_2` b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use if statement  in order to obtain the desired output

```
SELECT appsflyer_id, a.customer_id, status, IF (Status="NEW",0,balance) balance FROM `table_1` a left join `table_2` b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
```

Here the balance will be 0 (You can make it null/zero/empty as you wish) if the status is new else it will show the balance if there is more than 2 statuses you can consider using nested if

for more info refer the link below,

[MySQL  IF() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_if.asp)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `case` is to put the logic in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT a.appsflyer_id, a.customer_id, a.status, b.balance
FROM `table_1` a  LEFT JOIN
     `table_2` b 
     ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND a.status = 'ACTIVE'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

SELECT appsflyer_id, a.customer_id, status,
(SELECT balance FROM table_2 b WHERE a.cid=b.cid AND status='act') balance
FROM `table_1` a